# Return errors on ajax signup Rails devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

My customers signup on my website through an AJAX call. It works well if they signup is successful, but not if there are errors in their form. (the client side just does nothing).

FYI, I added the AJAX signup using this tutorial: [AJAX signup with devise Rails](https://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-set-up-devise-ajax-authentication-with-rails-4-0/)

but basically, the code is:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  respond_to :json

   # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end
end
```

and my signup form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true, label: "Prénom" %>
    <%= f.input :last_name, required: true, label: "Nom" %>

    <!-- Lots of fields here -->

    <%= f.button :submit, 'Valider' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What I would like to do is to display errors on top of the form thanks to the AJAX call, if there is any.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have used for my registration_controller for signing_up user.

```
class RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create, :cancel ]
  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      flash[:notice] = flash[:notice].to_a.concat resource.errors.full_messages
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And my form

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => devise_resource_name, :html => {:id => 'sign_up'}, :url => user_registration_path, :remote => :true) do |f| %>
<%#= devise_error_messages! %>
<%# flash.each do |key, value| %>
  # <div class="flash <%#= key %>"><%#= value %></div>
<%# end %>
```

In your create.js.erb
$("#id_or_class").html("<%= resource.errors.full_messages %>")

If you want to override the `devise_error_message`, here is the [reference](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Override-devise_error_messages!-for-views)

Comment: that seems to work on the server side, thank you very much! Now how do I display the errors on the client side ? (like over the form)

Comment: You mean flash message, like a banner ?

Comment: I just saw your edit thanks; well, just anything that would display the error once the customer submitted its form. I added your html code to display the `recource` but it does not show up :(

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @kedarnag ! unfortunately, I can't, manage to display errors to the user. Nothing gets on the screen form `devise_error_messages!`, notice that as I am using AJAX, my page does not reload

Comment: @JulesCorb Are you sure, I'm getting the errors, can you go into your view and after `<% = devise_error_messages! %>`, use a debugger and see what is the value of `flash` ?

Comment: Oh ok I did not notice your edit was also made on the controller; This will work but I do not want any redirection, I am actually looking for an AJAX signup + an AJAX error display. But thank you so much for your help anyway, I feel I'm close to the solution